# Is there an expression that means adopting someone's perspective?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Is there an expression that means adopting someone's perspective? Looking for an expression, phrase that means exactly that or something similar.

Comment: Hello fejojiniku! Can you edit your question to include an example sentence that demonstrates how the expression would be used?

Comment: Why was this closed? It's not off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiom that is commonly used is [put (oneself) in (someone's) shoes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+(oneself)+in+(someone%27s)+shoes)

> To imagine oneself in the situation or circumstances of another person, so as to understand or empathize with their perspective, opinion, or point of view.

Here are some examples from that link

- Before being quick to judge someone for their actions, you should always try to put yourself in their shoes. Everyone is human, after all.
- Put yourself in my shoes and then tell me what you would have done, Dan! It isn't as straightforward as you're making it seem!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

**take a leaf out of sb's book**

> to copy something that someone else does because it will bring you advantages:

*Maybe I should take a leaf out of Rick's book and start coming in early every morning.*

[Cambridge]

Answer (score -1):

How about "I'm adopting your perspective"?